# Keycloak Federation SPI changes

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to migrate an example user federation provider to a new version of keycloak (https://github.com/Smartling/keycloak-user-migration-provider) but I'm not finding any obvious documentation around incompatible API changes (i.e. the `UserFederationProvider` interface seems to have been replaced with several more specific interfaces, but there don't seem to be any examples of how to migrate between them).

I think I've gotten most of the changes by following the keycloak samples, but I'm confused where in the Smartling example `RemoteUserFederationProvider` makes use of the `UserModel` interface, which has an `updateCredential` method that seems to have been removed in the latest version. How should this be implemented in more recent versions of Keycloak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the UserModel change happened somewhere between Keycloak 1.7 and 2.0.

This snippet is from our Keycloak 2.0 implementation.

```
package org.sample.keycloak.federation;

import org.keycloak.models.UserCredentialModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserCredentialValueModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
import org.keycloak.models.utils.UserModelDelegate;

/**
 * Readonly proxy for a UserModel that prevents passwords from being updated.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:bill@burkecentral.com">Bill Burke</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1 $
 */
public class UserModelProxy extends UserModelDelegate {

    public UserModelProxy(UserModel delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Username is readonly");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCredentialDirectly(UserCredentialValueModel cred) {
        if (cred.getType().equals(UserCredentialModel.PASSWORD)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Passwords are readonly");
        }
        super.updateCredentialDirectly(cred);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCredential(UserCredentialModel cred) {
        if (cred.getType().equals(UserCredentialModel.PASSWORD)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Passwords are readonly");
        }
        super.updateCredential(cred);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.